# Include model data attributes in ASP.NET Web API action method result

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, attributes

When an ApiController Action returns a Model, **how do we include the model's data attributes / annotations in the payload?**

For instance, we would like to know that the UserName property is a required string displayed as "User Name".

Here is my model:

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Register")]
public RegisterBindingModel GetRegister()
{
    return new RegisterBindingModel();
}
```

Here is my get:

```
GET http://localhost:3067/api/Account/Register HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:3067
```

Here is my JSON response. The data attributes are not there.

```
{"UserName":null,"Password":null,"ConfirmPassword":null}
```

Whereas this is what we want:

```
{ 
  "UserName":{required:true, name:"User name",type:"string",value:null}, 
  "Password":{required:true, name:"Password,type:"password",value:null}, 
  "ConfirmPassword":{required:true, name:"Confirm Password,type:"password",value:null}
}
```

Comment: You can't do it from Web Api. If you need to construct your page, why you don't use MVC controller and HTML helpers like TextBoxFor/LabelFor/ValidationMessageFor etc?

Comment: That's a bummer. We are not using the MVC controller because the user interface is in AngularJS not ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Oh, this is for SPA. Have you tried [Breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/home)? Never used it by myself but heard it does some validation. Anyway you still could do server side validation (yes it's silly answer).

Comment: If you mean Single Page Application, then yes it is for SPA. Server side validation is fine. The problem, though, is in creating a dynamic form. For instance, we would need to know that an input is of boolean type to create a radio button list. There might be a work-around by setting default values for primitive types.